# CakePHP Mobile Website

Tags: cakephp, mobile, web

Any idea, how can we create already running website to Mobile Website?

Are there, ready made plug-ins / components available ?

I've found some like wapple.net however it is paid one, which is not feasible for client's budget.

I have found, XML creations is pretty easy in CakePHP, though your ideas would be appreciated.

Kindly share more details on the same !

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i dont think that you'll find a plugin that will transform your website for mobile. because there are too many decisions to make when creating a mobile web, for me it's like creating a completly different website with only the necessary information that your website has..

But maybe there are components that might help you with the small taks (like detecting the user agent and stuff).. here you can read two good articles about creating a mobile website:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/13/mobile-web-design-trends-2009/

There's also a few JS frameworks that will help you with the interaction with the user, i've only used [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)..

But my guess is that you'll have to adapt/create "manually" the css, html and js for mobile, and I don't think that there's a magical tool to do that, you'll have to do it yourself (or pay someone to do it =D)

Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Typically with cakephp you want to create a separate view layout for mobile viewing. The app controller should change the default view layout to the mobile one when detecting a mobile browser.

Your mobile view layout should be made by you, only you know what data on your site is important and what is not (aka, what should be removed /kept for mobile viewing) Also your mobile layout can use alternate CSS and only load the elements you want.

To learn more about creating views in cakephp see the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts):

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in my answer over here:

[CakePHP v2.2.1 Solution (+ Cookies to persist mobile/desktop/other layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131701/114140)

In a nutshell:

1. Lets you setup mobile layouts `/Views/Layouts/mobile/default.ctp`
2. Mobile views `/Views/Pages/mobile/home.ctp`
3. Sets a template variable `$is_mobile`
4. Lets you force a specific layout `?forcedLayout=desktop`, and remembers this in a COOKIE
5. If no layout is forced it uses CakePHP's User-Agent detection to make the decision `$this->request->is('mobile')`
6. If no `../mobile/` layout or view file exists then it falls back to the default layout or view.