# Cakephp Mobile layout Home redirect. (RequestHandler->isMobile() )

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-mobile

Im trying to buil a mobile version of my website, usign Cakephp and JQueyrMobile.
For the Cakephp part i opted to use the following in app_controller:

```
    if($this->RequestHandler->isMobile() || isset($this->params['url']['mobile'])) {
       $this->layout = 'mobile';
       $this->isMobile = true;
    }
    $this->set('is_mobile', $this->isMobile);

    if($this->isMobile) {
           $this->action = 'mobile/'.$this->action;
     }
```

Thank i create the /mobile/ folder for every controller/view and it works fine.
I just have a problem with the home.ctp ! i created the alternative mobile version in /views/pages/mobile/home.ctp but it loads the /views/pages/home.ctp.

What should i do in order to redirect to the mobile version of home.ctp usign the code above ?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you fixed this ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `beforeFilter` and `afterFilter` in your AppController?

I use this for the mobile version of one of my Cake applications:

```
  function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
      $this->is_mobile = true;
      $this->set('is_mobile', true );
      $this->autoRender = false;
    }
  }
```

And afterFilter:

```
  function afterFilter() {
    if (isset($this->is_mobile) && $this->is_mobile) {
      $view_file = file_exists( VIEWS . $this->name . DS . 'mobile/' . $this->action . '.ctp' );
      $layout_file = file_exists( LAYOUTS . 'mobile/' . $this->layout . '.ctp' );
      $this->render($this->action, ($layout_file?'mobile/':'').$this->layout, ($view_file?'mobile/':'').$this->action);
    }
  }
```

This code comes from another question on mobile content in Cake, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891310/cakephp-website-mobile-version/3891949#3891949) for more information. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891310/cakephp-website-mobile-version/7005008#7005008) on that same question deals with layouts.